# How to apply multiprocessing pool python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

How should I apply the python multiprocessing pool on my function that scrapes data from internet using the list of provided urls in xml format. There can be multiple url files at one time. It then generates two output files having specific extracted  results in one and some in second. Also the name of log file created is passed in function.
Below is current example I have tried with multiprocessing process function. But I think it will definitely create forkbomb. So I am considering to use thread pool for this. My CPU has 8 cores.

```
Def proclaunch():
 os.system("scrap2.py "+in.xml+ " " +out1.csv+" "+ out2.csv+ " "+log.txt)


Def prochandler():
 LstProc=[]
 For flist in lstfiles:
    proc =    Process(target=proclaunch,args(flist[0],flist[1],flist[2],flist[3])
    LstProc.append(proc)
  
  For p in LstProc:
     P.start()
  
  For p in LstProc:
    P.join()
```

I have tried using multiprocessing Process function but it may create fork bomb .I think multiprocessing pool should be used but can't figure out how to apply it .

Comment: Here's an example of how to use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`: https://superfastpython.com/threadpool-map/

Comment: By the way, is your goal to use threads or processes? Your code example uses processes, but your question asks about threads. For this problem, I would recommend threads.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: asyncio (coroutines) would be the most performant in the case of a web scraper. There is a good article on concurrency with similar examples of accessing web data here: https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#asyncio-version

Comment: I have looked at examples but can't figure out how to apply multiprocessing pool.

Comment: Also, please correct your code snippet: it is not valid syntactic Python: All statements should be lower case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I have a function that accept multiple values I pass them as a list.

## Multi proicessing

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tqdm import tqdm


def parallel_threads(fun, vec, pbar=True):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        if pbar:
            results = list(tqdm(
                executor.map(fun, vec),
                total=len(vec)))
        else:
            results = list(
                executor.map(fun, vec))
    return results
```

## Function

Let says you function accept multiple values

```py
def fun(a, b, c):
    ...
```

you define a wrap function such that

```py
def wrap_fun(vec):
    a, b, c = vec
    fun(a, b, c)
```

Then you need a list of list like

```py
lst = [[a_1, b_1, c_1], 
       [a_2, b_2, c_2], 
       ... ,
       [a_n, b_n,c_n]]
```

and you can run it

```py
out = parallel_threads(wrap_fun, lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

As say in a comment, you won't use multiprocessing for web scraping bu rather multi-threading or even better an asynchronous I/O library such as Python AsyncIO.

Here is an example using a thread pool:

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


# Replace this function with your actual 
# web scraping logic.
def fetch(url: str) -> str:
    result = requests.get(url)
    return result.text


def main():
    urls = ["url_1", "url_2", "url_3"]

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        results = pool.map(fetch, urls)

    for result in results:
        print(f"{result}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This creates a pool of 8 threads (if your computer has 8 cores) and executes the web-scraping function `fetch` concurrently on it.

This is what is would look like using AsyncIO and AIOHTTP instead:

```py
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def fetch(url: str, session: ClientSession) -> str:
    async with session.get(url=url) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def main():
    urls = ["url_1", "url_2", "url_3"]

    with ClientSession() as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*(fetch(url, session) for url in urls))

    for result in results:
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Note that in most cases you should use a `TCPConnector` to limit the concurrency, otherwise you'll likely be rejected by the server for issuing too many concurrent requests (the same applies for the multi-threaded solution).

Depending on your use case (you should show us the content of `scrap2.py` for that), you could also use process the scraping output as they are completed instead of when they are all completed using the `as_completed` function.